# gnome-panel crashed, and now won't load in GNOME Flashback (Metacity and Compiz)

Tags: gnome, compiz, gnome-panel, gnome-classic, metacity

I installed GNOME Flashback earlier today because I prefer the old interface.  While surfing the web earlier, gnome-panel crashed.  I thought it would be no big deal, but it didn't come back like I expected, so I rebooted.  Ever since, I have been unable to get it to launch.  I can access Unity fine (posting from Unity right now), but both Metacity and Compiz GNOME Flashback sessions log in, show my wallpaper, and my start-up apps load, but no gnome-panel.

I've uninstalled and re-installed gnome-session-flashback (purged on uninstall), no luck.  Yes, I even tried turning it off and on again (sorry, had to throw that in there).

/var/log/syslog says that gnome-panel.desktop was killed with signal 6, and ~/.xsession-errors shows that indicator-application main process ended (2x) and then says it stopped trying to respawn it.

Has anyone seen this issue, and if so, is there a solution?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a bug, which should be [reported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#How_to_report_bugs) at launchpad.net.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I'd check here before I did that just to make sure I wasn't being an idiot and missing something.  I'll file one tonight or tomorrow after I try troubleshooting while actually awake...  Troubleshooting at 2 AM isn't always very productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**  I broke it again (about 5-10 mins after posting my original answer below)... then I fixed it!  Turns out, when I was adding a new app to the Applications menu in flashback using *alacarte* it happened again, so I went to kill all my .desktop files, and as it turns out I somehow corrupted something in *~/.config/menus*.

Specifically, I added an entry to the Internet category, and it created a duplicate Internet entry, and when trying to hide that, gnome-panel crashed.

Let's see if I can do what I want without breaking things...

---

After taking some more time to troubleshoot the issue, I've found that it's something specific to my user account.  I tried logging in as a guest with gnome-flashback (as I should have done originally) and it worked!

I tried clearing all my Unity, Metacity, Gnome, and Compiz settings with no luck.  I tried reinstaling flashback, compiz, and making sure everything was up to date.  None of these helped.  I can only suspect that a file got corrupted somehow in a settings file I didn't know to reset.

Seeing as I'm more familiar with Ubuntu Server than I am desktop, **I decided to backup my home directory, delete my user account, and re-create it and restore my documents, music, etc. from the backup.**

So far so good.  It's working like a charm now.  Will it happen again?  Maybe (more likely than not with my luck), but hopefully not.